# AWS S3: IAM Policy with Deny IP Block Denies All IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an IAM policy bound to a user that includes a block like:

```
...
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "0.0.0.0/0"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
...
```

If my understanding is correct, this should allow *any* IP -- this block should have no effect.  However, when I try to do some S3 operations as a user that is bound to this policy, the actions yield Access Denied.  When I remove this block from the IAM policy, the S3 operations are allowed.

What is wrong with this policy, or my understanding thereof?

I've tried a similar policy but with a real array of IPs I want to allow through, but same result -- so I figured this would be a better minimal example to clarify my understanding.

Comment: How about if you update 3


You should update your Deny policy to include operations that are performed on the bucket itself?

Comment: Why do you even need `NotIpAddress` in your case?

Comment: Also how exactly do you test that?

Comment: I am using an aws s3api put-object CLI command to test.  Obviously for 0.0.0.0/0 this block shouldn’t be needed but what I’d really like is my array of trusted IPs.  But using that array or 0.0.0.0/0 gives the same (access denied) result when running from one of my trusted IPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the actual list of trusted IPs, it turns out that S3 was seeing the *internal* IPs of the source nodes, not their *external* IPs (which is what I was including in the list).  Filtering based on the internal IPs or based on the VPC ID that contained all the nodes worked.  This still doesn't explain why a filter using 0.0.0.0/0 as above blocked any traffic, but hopefully this helps in case anyone else runs into something like this.